# All CSS working in Sencha Touch 2 list except for one property

Tags: css, list, colors, sencha-touch-2

My list loads data, works fine and all CSS is being applied to each Cls except for the font color in the SelectedCls where I have the .ListSelected class.

The text should be white when selected state.

```
    .ListNormal {
        background: #f7f7f7;
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #024059 !important;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
    }

    .ListPressed {
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #024059 !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
        background: #b6e1ff;
    }

    .ListSelected {
        font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #ffffff !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1ca1ff), to(#0081dc));
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #b1dfff;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you use !important, the first property takes precedence over other properties with !important farther down in the sheet.  The opposite is the case on properties where !important is not used (last takes precedence). One of your other classes is taking precedence over your selected class.

Comment: And that's why !important declarations should not be used unless they are absolutely necessary.

Comment: Sencha overrides so much CSS that sometimes it almost is necessary.

Even with removing the !important, it's still not accepting that color property. Any other suggestions? Or is it possible that something else in my CSS with an !important tag is taking precedence?

Comment: @TDeBailleul your link here is what I'm trying to do, when I click on one of the rows, the text changes to white so it's visible on the blue. Is that Senchas CSS or a custom style sheet you made http://titouanvanbelle.fr/GitHub/Sencha/Ext.ux.DeleteButton/

Comment: I believe it is Sencha's CSS. I haven't customize this widget. But !important is not the only way to prioritize CSS : http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: @TDeBailleul thank you tons for your help and for that article. I only began using it when our offshore developers used it, hence what the article says about inheriting the problem. Looks like I've got a lot of work to do. Thanks again